# Alpine.js Form has Multiple Selects, How to get Option values?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alpine.js

Using Alpine.js how do you get the value of `select1` or `select2` in the main `form()` function?

I can do it if I don't use `x-data` on the Selects, but then you have to do funky things with the `open` variable so it is unique for each Select (if you don't, then all the Selects open at once).

Notes:

- I'm **not** using `x-for` to iterate the Select Option inputs because for performance reasons I'm pre-rendering those in HTML. They have icons and there is over 250 of them.
- Is the `@click="$dispatch('input', 'option1Key')"` technique the best way to set the value of the selected option, since not using an actual select input and x-for?

```html
<div x-data="form()">

  <!-- snip other fields like regular inputs -->

  <label for="select-1">Select 1</label>
  <div x-data="{ select1: '', open: false }">
    <div>Selected: <span x-text="select1"></span></div>
    <button @click="open=true">Select ...</button>
    <ul x-show="open" @click.away="open=false" x-model="select1" style="display: none;">
      <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option1Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option1</li>
      <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option2Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <label for="select-2">Select 2</label>
  <div x-data="{ select2: '', open: false }">
    <div>Selected: <span x-text="select2"></span></div>
    <button @click="open=true">Select ...</button>
    <ul x-show="open" @click.away="open=false" x-model="select2" style="display: none;">
      <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option1Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option1</li>
      <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option2Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <button class="search" type="submit" :disabled="loading" @click="search()">Search</button>

</div>
```

```js
<script>
function form() {
  return {
    select1: '',
    select2: '',
    search() {
      console.log(select1); // undefined
      console.log(select2); // undefined
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, we discussed this through another channel but the way to fix this issue is to have a single Alpine component (x-data)

```html
<div x-data="f()">

  <!-- snip other fields like regular inputs -->

  <div class="select">
    <label for="select-1">Select 1 Label</label>
    <div>
      <div class="output">x-text "select1": <span x-text="select1"></span></div>
      <button @click="open='select1'">Click to Select1 ...</button>
      <ul x-show="open === 'select1'" @click.away="open=null" x-model="select1">
        <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option1Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option1</li>
        <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option2Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="select">
    <label for="select-2">Select 2 Label</label>
    <div>
      <div class="output">x-text "select2": <span x-text="select2"></span></div>
      <button @click="open='select2'">Click to Select2 ...</button>
      <ul x-show="open === 'select2'" @click.away="open=null" x-model="select2">
        <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option1Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option1</li>
        <li @click="$dispatch('input', 'option2Key')"><i class="icon"></i> Option2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="search" type="submit" :disabled="loading" @click="search()">Search</button>

</div>
```

Script

```js
function f() {
  return {
    open: null,
    loading: false,
    select1: '',
    select2: '',
    search() {
      console.log('select1 value: ' + "'" + this.select1 + "'"); // ''
      console.log('select2 value: ' + "'" + this.select2 + "'"); // ''
    },
  };
}
```

The fills working fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/w7hg341m/9/